# Setting Null Value For Column Using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement that says "update columns using modifying queries". This way I won't have to make a select statement in the database (Oracle), and it updates if, and only if, it finds a row with my where clause. However, I am not able to use null values in the update query. I don't want to worry about creating different queries and check in the service class if the value is null or not to call these different queries. The repository.save(entity) works just fine. I have more columns that can be null and they are saved as null. The COLUMN_1 (NUMBER) and COLUMN_2 (VARCHAR) I mention are NOT NULL.

**Is there a way to work with @Modifying queries and null values and let NVL or any other SQL function decide which value it should use? The error specifically says the types I use are not the ones it expects. It seems like the null values are converted into BINARY OR VARBINARY.**

I know I could do something like this using SQL and it works just fine:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME tb SET COLUMN_1 = nvl(:test, COLUMN_1) WHERE ID = 123456;
```

It is going to ignore the **:test** value if it is null and use the current column value. However, if I do the same using JPA an error occurs. The code:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value =
            "UPDATE TABLE_NAME TB" +
            "SET TB.COLUMN_1 = NVL(:column1, TB.COLUMN_1), " +
            "    TB.COLUMN_2 = NVL(:column2, TB.COLUMN_2) " +
            "WHERE TB.ID= :id" +
            "    AND TB.CURRENT_RECORD = :mostRecentFlag ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public int updateRow(Integer id, BigInteger column1, String column2, int mostRecentFlag);
```

JPA creates the update the right way:

```
    UPDATE
        TABLE_NAME TB
    SET
        TB.COLUMN_1 = NVL(?, TB.COLUMN_1),
        TB.COLUMN_2 = NVL(?, TB.COLUMN_2)
    WHERE
        TB.ID= ?     
        AND TB.CURRENT_RECORD = ?
```

It also binds the values the right way:

```
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [52]
binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [username]
binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [123456]
binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

However, I always get an error no matter what. If the VARCHAR column is null:

```
12-01-2022 16:26:22.993 [] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:137 - SQL Error: 1465, SQLState: 72000
12-01-2022 16:26:22.993 [] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:142 - ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

But also for the NUMBER column:

```
12-01-2022 16:38:03.782 [] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:137 - SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
12-01-2022 16:38:03.782 [] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:142 - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER
```

I have tried things like SpEL but it didn't work as well:

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value =
            "UPDATE TABLE_NAME TB" +
            "SET TB.COLUMN_1 = NVL(:column1, TB.COLUMN_1), " +
            "    TB.COLUMN_2 = #{#column2?:'TB.COLUMN_2'} " +
            "WHERE TB.ID= :id" +
            "    AND TB.CURRENT_RECORD = :mostRecentFlag ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public int updateRow(Integer id, BigInteger column1, String column2, int mostRecentFlag);
```

It saved the literal **TB.COLUMN_2** instead.
The whole stack error for the VARCHAR case:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.updateDevice(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1549) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:241) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

The whole stacktrace for the NUMBER case:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.updateDevice(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1549) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:241) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Spring version:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

**EDIT**

panagiotis-bougioukos suggested I should use case espression. Forgot to mention I already tried but it got the same error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

Generated query

```
    UPDATE
        TABLE_NAME TB
    SET
        TB.COLUMN_1 =  CASE         
            WHEN ? IS NULL THEN TB.COLUMN_1         
            ELSE ?     
        END,
        TB.COLUMN_2 = NVL(?, TB.COLUMN_2)
    WHERE
        TB.ID= ?     
        AND TB.CURRENT_RECORD = ?
```